# Don't mind if I diddly-do

Tags: meaning

Source:   [1]: https://vm.tiktok.com/ZM8TWDvQb/

A McDonald drive-thru tiktok video went viral recently.
The staff on the speaker was amazing doing his job.
When he asked what drink the customer wanted for the meal, he went like:

> Oi oi Saveloy, what drink do you like for that bad boy?

When the customer ordered two "7-up", he said:

> That's 14-up.

When the customer asked "no lettuce please"， he went like:

> No lettuce, no worries.

When the customer ordered "chocolate milk shake", he said：

> Choccy shake. Don't mind if i diddly-do.

Does "diddly-do" here means:

> A. my playing with the words

> B. my being cool, showing off

Or there's better explaination in this context?

Comment: surely most instances of playing with the words are in order to show off. That is, A==B

Answer (score 3):

The man is obviously using funny language and playing with words. Do not take what he is saying as standard English.

The base sentence is "Don't mind if I do" (which means "I will go ahead and do what you suggested"—a somewhat strange thing to say to a customer who has **requested** something, but again, the man is having fun with language). Adding the syllables "diddly" before "do" adds absolutely nothing to the meaning of the sentence; it is simply an ornamentation added for fun. It is similar to the way a character named Ned Flanders on the TV show *The Simpsons* talks.

Comment: I live in a district of Bristol (UK) called St Werburghs, and I have lost count of the number of taxi drivers who say 'You want to go to Saint Whirlyburgs?' Very mildly funny the first time you hear it, less so the fiftieth.

Comment: Thanks Randomhead!! Does "on that bad boy" refer to the meal the customer ordered? Or refer to the customer who might be a "bad boy"?

Comment: @district12 - 'that bad boy' is a standard US idiom meaning 'that thing we are talking about'.